# Generate an array of letters of alphabet in non-english and add different value for each letter in C# or VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to generate an alphabet (strAbc) and add a different value (strAbcVal) to each letter (strAbc) where some letters have a two char, like (DŽ,NJ,LJ), and than sum string sName 
Can you help me?

```
dim sName as string ="LJILJANA"

dim strAbc as string ="A,B,C,D,Đ,DŽ,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,LJ,M,N,NJ,O,P,R,S,Š,T,U,V,Z,Ž"

dim strAbcVal as string="11,2,7,14,5,9,7,15,9,10,16,12,9,3,5,4,12,11,22,70,61,22,50,14,1,2,7,15,19,40"
```

Comment: Something that get me a value for sName string

Comment: What is the desired result for `sName` string? So you want to sum each letter in `sName` which according integers in `strAbcVal` and their letters in `strAbc`? Use a `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)` to calculate the sum.

Comment: By the way, there are 2 valaues more than according letters. Please tell us the rules for your calculation and what you've tried (-1)

Comment: first off i probably wouldnt have a Character string and its Value string.  I would probably do a KeyValuePair collection and have the Letters be the `Key` and the associated numerical value as the `Value` part of the association.  That way you can do an easy search for the letters.  Your biggest problem, initially will be that if you have a legitimate situation where, per say the combo `LJ` was actually meant to be interpretted as `L` & `J` individually.  So you will need to put further login in to handle this situation and put a heirarchy of substitution in the Collection as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is just a guess, because I'm not sure what you're aiming for but did you consider using a `Dictionary` object?

A `Dictionary` works like a dictionary in the real world. You have the unique keys and to each such key you have a corresponding value. In your case, the letters (or combos of letters) would be the keys and the numbers the actual values.

(Of course, since ut seems to be a 1-to-1 relation, the numbers can be used as keys as well.)

Please elaborate on your goal.